# Disable FN + C (other answers online do not work)

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

I use FN as a key inside emacs. Unfortunately, FN C (which I need to use) is bound to open Control Center. Looking in shortcuts, there is no way to disable this one.

I have press fn key to -> do nothing

Disabling the FN key completely does not do what I want because then it won't work and be caught in emacs.

For example, for FN Q, there is a shortcut attached. If you remove it, then it's free for use. That's what I want.

Comment: Fn C does not have any function on my Mac

Comment: @Ruskes it opens Control Center for me (as for the OP), with Sonoma and a Magic Keyboard.